# Hide/show function jquery or javascript calling more than one action, but not at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i want to make a remove player button, so that everytime i click it, it hides a images/button, the same for a add player function.

```
function addplayer(){
for (var i = 51; i <= 94; i++) {
    if (i == 51 || i == 61 ||){
  $("#" + "addplayer" + i).show();
}
}
}
```

This is my html caller

```
  <button onclick="addplayer();"style="bottom:55;position:fixed;right:10;width:100;height:40px;background-color:#FFFFFF;">addplayer</button>

  document.getElementById("addplayer2").onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById("51Container").style.display="inline-block";
  document.getElementById("52Container").style.display="inline-block";
  document.getElementById("53Container").style.display="inline-block";
  document.getElementById("54Container").style.display="inline-block";
}
document.getElementById("addplayer3").onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById("61Container").style.display="inline-block";
  document.getElementById("62Container").style.display="inline-block";
  document.getElementById("63Container").style.display="inline-block";
  document.getElementById("64Container").style.display="inline-block";
}
```

(i got 6 in total completly looking the same), just to illustrate, how it would work
Theese are my add player function, just on 5 different buttons, just to showcase that it is doing something, it doest seem to work for me, how do i do this, so that the same button will add (show), different object instead of the solution i got atm.

Hope somebody will help me.

Comment: Are you trying to get `addplayer()` to call the `onclick` event for each of the player links based on the index `i`?

Comment: Yes i do, wouldnt that be the easiest way of solving the problem ?

Comment: I needs to remove 1 per click

Comment: What are your elements `addplayer2` and `addplayer3` defined as? Buttons? Hyperlinks? Likewise - what are your `51Container` and `52Container` etc defined as?

Comment: <button id="addplayer2" style="display: inline-block"> Add player</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to invoke the function which is assigned to the `addplayer#` control, instead of calling `$("#addplayer" + i).show()` try calling `$("#addplayer" + i).click()` .. however, based on our back-and-forth, it seems that your `i` needs some attention.

As you said, your `addplayer#` controls are buttons, therefore, I suggest the following:

```
function addplayer(){
  $("button[id^='addplayer']").each(function(i,e) { $(e).click(); });
}
```

This will invoke any click event function defined for any buttons whose id starts with `addplayer`.

See this fiddle for an example of how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/qhevn1x3/2/

---

Although I do not know your page's exact makeup, I would suggest something along these lines (if possible):

```
<div id='51Container'>some player</div>
<button class="addPlayer" data-id="51">Add Player</button>
<button class="removePlayer" data-id="51">Remove Player</button>
```

Then my JS would be something like:

```
// Page-level execution to assign my click events
$(function() {
  $("button.addPlayer").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#" + id + "Container").css({'display':'inline-block'});
    $("button.addPlayer[data-id='" + id + "']").toggle();
    $("button.removePlayer[data-id='" + id + "']").toggle();
  });
  $("button.removePlayer").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#" + id + "Container").css({'display':'none'});
    $("button.addPlayer[data-id='" + id + "']").toggle();
    $("button.removePlayer[data-id='" + id + "']").toggle();
  });
})();
```

This will wire up the add/remove buttons with the corresponding player. Then, if you wish to have a button to hide/show multiple, you need only select the appropriate add/remove buttons (by filtering by data-id) and invoke their click events.